# Starting cmd-console from another program by ShellExecute: What to enther that cmd stays open after script finishes?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am starting my ps-script by Windows' ShellExecuteW(..):

```
  #import "shell32.dll"
      int ShellExecuteW(int hWnd,int lpVerb,string lpFile,string lpParameters,string lpDirectory,int nCmdShow);
  #import
  ....
  string psDir = "C:\\Users...\\WindowsPowerShell";
  string param = "-file loadPOP2emails.ps1";
  int ret = ShellExecuteW(0,0, "powershell.exe", param, psDir, SW_SHOW);
```

What do I have to enter in the param-string that the console remains open after the script has finished?
Any hint that I can try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `-noexit` that's a powershell console not a cmd one..

Comment: Why use ShellExecute? Why not just use `start-process`?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I don't start my script from ps but from another program, that has it's own c-like language. To do something 'outside' of this language one has to use imported Windows dll.

Comment: Never mind...I wasn't paying very good attention that your code is not PowerShell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter needed to keep powershell open is NoExit

```
  string param = "-NoExit -file loadPOP2emails.ps1";
```